# somebody takes some time to do something vs It takes somebody some time to do something

Tags: active-vs-passive

Occasionally, I come across the following

> Somebody takes seconds/minutes/hours/days/etc to do something

on the Internet, which does not seem as common as

> It takes somebody seconds/minutes/hours/days/etc to do something.

How grammatically correct is the former?

For example, which of the following is the most natural sounding and why.

> - We took three hours to put the child to bed.
> - It took us three hours to put the child to bed.
> - The child took us three hours to put (him/her) to bed.
> - Taking the child to bed took us three hours.

Comment: Are you suggesting that *My wife takes hours to get dressed when we're getting ready to go out* should be replaced by ***It takes** my wife hours to get dressed when we're getting ready to go out*? They're ***both*** perfectly natural phrasings.

Comment: As this is an English site, could you please endeavour to type in English, rather than txt spk.

Comment: Can you give actual example sentences? Both phrases might be valid but it would depend what sbd, some time, and sth were replaced by, and what sentence they were in.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. I've edited the question and translated it into English. I agree with you and would point out that not everyone can understand texteese.

Comment: Is there a reason why you think the former would be "less grammatical"?

Comment: We took three hours to put the child to bed.
vs
It took us three hours to put the child to bed.
vs
The child took us three hours to put (him/her) to bed.
vs
Taking the child to bed took us three hours.

Answer (score -1):

> 'somebody takes hours to do something'

Implication / translation: Somebody is doing some task, and it takes him hours.

> 'it takes somebody hours to do something'

Implication / translation: In order to complete the task, it takes somebody hours. This emphasizes the sentence, and is commonly used if wanting to complain / make a point / hyperbolize: "Ugh! It takes me HOURS to do this."

They are both completely grammatically correct. They may have very very slightly different connotations.